# How to move/resize xfce4-terminal using the command line?

Tags: xfce, window, resize, xfce4-terminal

How do I move and resize the xfce4-terminal by command line?

The problem is that the command `echo -ne '\e[3;0;0t'` does not re-position my `xfce4-terminal` and has no apparent affect. `man xfce4-terminal` and other answers suggest it should.

> xfce4-terminal emulates the xterm application developed by the X
>          Consortium. In turn, the xterm application emulates the DEC VT102
>          terminal and also supports the DEC VT220 escape sequences.

http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html

http://rtfm.etla.org/xterm/ctlseq.html

The goal is to write a script that creates a few terminals and sets up my working environment without needing to click and resize my terminals to my comfort.

What does work is `echo -ne '\e[8;40;80t'` which the causes the terminal to resize correctly. So why not moving the window?

---

Other information that I am unsure may affect anything:

I have tried other numbers such as the sequence `'\e[3;100;100t'` but nothing seems to relocate the terminal window.

I am actually running ubuntu and installed and launch with xfce4 after unity started having issues from an update.

> xfce4-terminal 0.6.3 (Xfce 4.10)

Comment: `xfce4-terminal` supports the `--geometry` option, you can use it like this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48984/how-can-i-set-the-position-that-terminal-opens-at

Comment: Try `wmctrl`, can be found in repos.

Comment: Upvoted for research and useful references

Answer (score 2):

The man page for `xfce4-terminal` specifies using the `--geometry` option to set the size and placement of a terminal.

This flag uses the options  *"**-geometry WIDTHxHEIGHT+XOFF+YOFF** (where WIDTH, HEIGHT, XOFF, and YOFF are numbers) for specifying a preferred size and location for this application's main window."*

Refer to the "Geometry Specifications" section of the man page for X (`man X`).

Here are several examples of xterm placement:

1. Place a short and wide terminal window on upper left-hand side of the display:

   `xfce4-terminal --geometry 140x20+50+50`
2. Place a square terminal window in the lower left-hand corner of the display:

   `xfce4-terminal --geometry 100x40+40+500`
3. Place a square terminal window in the upper right-hand corner of the display:

   `xfce4-terminal --geometry 100x40+1500+40`
4. Place a short and wide terminal window on lower right-hand side of the display:

   `xfce4-terminal --geometry 140x20+1500+500`

If you would like to make this setting permanent, follow these instructions:

*"copy the terminal launcher (terminal's .desktop file) from `/usr/share/applications/` to `~/.local/share/applications/` and edit the Exec field accordingly"* as mentioned in the answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48984/how-can-i-set-the-position-that-terminal-opens-at).

Comment: This is ok, but I don't really think this 'fully' answer's the OP's question. This obviously works for spawning new terminals (with the --geometry flag, so +1 for that part) but how can you resize/move the current terminal? I have found `resize -s <rows> <cols>` also works, but I can't find how to re-position the current terminal (lets say while a script is running so opening a new terminal is not really an option.).... is it possible?